# class inherit and passing the value to derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm totally new to c++ , and trying to learn the inherit of the class . when i build an array  and try to call the derived class with the array as an argument , the passing value changed to 0 . and I couldn't figure why . Please help ! thx .

When I run the main , it suppose to show 1.5, 2.5,3.5 , 4.5, 5.5, but it showed ,
 1.5
2.5
0
4.5
5.5
I tried cout nums[2]  in main , it showed 3.5 , I don't know why when the B obj called , it become 0 . 
here is the code:

```cpp
#include "B_double.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



int main() {
  double nums[5] = {1.5, 2.5,3.5 , 4.5, 5.5};
  cout << nums[2]<< endl;


  B_double myObj(nums, 6);
  myObj.printBuffer();

  return 0;
}
```

```cpp
#ifndef A_H_
#define A_H_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;

class A{
protected :
    int * x ;
private :
    void initialize (int);
    void cleanup();
public:
    A(int i);
    virtual ~A();
    int getX()const;
    void setX(int);
};
#endif /* A_H_ */
```

```cpp
#include "A.h"
using namespace std ;

void A::initialize(int i){
    x = new int(i);
}

void A:: cleanup(){
    delete x;
}

A::A(int i){

    *x = 0 ;
    initialize (i);
}

A::~A(){
    cleanup();
}

int A:: getX()const{
    return *x;
}

void A:: setX(int i){
    *x = i;
}
```

```cpp
#ifndef B_DOUBLE_HPP_
#define B_DOUBLE_HPP_

#include<iostream>
#include "A.h"

using namespace std ;


class B_double : public A{
private :
    double buffer[5];
public:
    B_double( double* , int i);
    void printBuffer()const;


};

#endif /* B_HPP_ */
```

```cpp
B_double::B_double(double* arr, int i): A(i){



for ( int m = 0 ; m<5; m++){
    cout << arr[m] << endl;
}

    for ( int j = 0 ; j<5; j++){
        buffer[j] = arr[j];
        cout <<buffer[j]<< ",";
    }

}



void B_double::printBuffer()const{
    for (int i = 0 ; i< 5 ; i++){
        cout << this->buffer[i]<<",";
    }
}
```

```cpp
#ifndef B_DOUBLE_HPP_
#define B_DOUBLE_HPP_

#include<iostream>
#include "A.h"

using namespace std ;


class B_double : public A{
private :
    double buffer[5];
public:
    B_double( double* , int i);
    void printBuffer()const;


};

#endif /* B_HPP_ */
```

```cpp
B_double::B_double(double* arr, int i): A(i){



for ( int m = 0 ; m<5; m++){
    cout << arr[m] << endl;
}

    for ( int j = 0 ; j<5; j++){
        buffer[j] = arr[j];
        cout <<buffer[j]<< ",";
    }

}



void B_double::printBuffer()const{
    for (int i = 0 ; i< 5 ; i++){
        cout << this->buffer[i]<<",";
    }
}
```

Comment: in `A::A(int i)`, the statement `*x = 0` - invokes *undefined behavior*. The member `x` was never set to a determinate state (which seems to happen in `initialize`, but that's *after* the offending statement. Therefore, `*x = ...` dereferences an indeterminate pointer `x`. Frankly I don't see the reason `x` is dynamic in the first place.

Comment: thanks , that solve the problem . I actually have more question about constructor , the UML given for the class is + A(i = 0 : int)  and - initialize(i : int) :. I always confused why we need a initialize function in the first place , can I just construct everything in the constructor ? anyway that's how teacher taught , so I dont' know ....

Comment: You're **supposed** to construct everything in the ctor, in fact, you're encouraged to initialize members *in place* with ctor member initializer lists, just be careful with calling functions in it, it can result in UB.

Comment: by ctor , do you mean constructor ? I'm now familiar with the word ...

Comment: @javier Silva Ortiz and what does "for initialize members in place" mean ? for example for this A class, should I construct like    A::A(int i = 0){

 
 initialize (i);
}   will that cause the same problem as the statement *x = 0;